# finding/getting selected index on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a ASP page with a select list.

I populated the list just fine,but when it submits the post-back is of the text value of the selected item but I need the index.

Is there a way to find that?
Either is there a way to find the index using the value?
or
Is there a way to get the index to post-back instead of the value?

Here is how I am getting the value

```
 Request.Form("Select1")
```

Can anyone help either in VB or C#?

Comment: how are you building you select list?

Comment: If Not IsPostBack Then
            source = Session("source")
            callList = Session("callList")
            siteUrl = Session("URL")
            Select1.Items.Clear()
            For i = 0 To callList.Count - 2
                Select1.Items.Add("ID:" & callList(i).tag &      "Customer:" & callList(i).addressList(1).address)
                Select1.Value = callList(i).key
            Next
     end if